# AngularJS doesn't work with another JQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp

I have got an AngularJS function that shows me a hidden form clicking on button. But when i added function that fills inputs, into modal window, from table's values, i'm clicking at button that shows me a form and it doesn't work. It shows me next message

> jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Here is my JSP page with scripts.

```
    <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<c:set var="language"
    value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}"
    scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="ua.khpi.shapoval.i18n.lang" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><fmt:message key="users.anotheruser" /></title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/styles.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular/angular.min.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <%@ include file="/fragments/header.jspf"%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 centerBlock">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th><fmt:message key="profile.name" /></th>
                <th><fmt:message key="profile.surname" /></th>
                <th><fmt:message key="profile.login" /></th>
                <th><fmt:message key="profile.email" /></th>

                <th><fmt:message key="profile.countofcars" /></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.surname}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.login}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>

                <td><c:out value="${countOfCars}" /></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div class="centerBlock text-center col-xs-8 ">
        <div ng-app="auto" ng-controller="carController">

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " ng-click="addCarFunc()">
                <fmt:message key="cars.addcar" />
            </button>

            <div ng-show="showForm">
                <div class="col-xs-4 centerBlock text-center">
                    <form action="/Autostation/users" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"><fmt:message
                                    key="profile.car.model" /> </label> <input
                                class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="model"
                                name="model" required="true" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"><fmt:message
                                    key="profile.car.type" /> </label> <select
                                class="form-control input-sm" name="type">
                                <option value="1"><fmt:message key="cars.mini" /></option>
                                <option value="2"><fmt:message key="cars.city" /></option>
                                <option value="3"><fmt:message key="cars.van" /></option>
                                <option value="4"><fmt:message key="cars.cargo" /></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"><fmt:message
                                    key="profile.car.serviceability" /> </label> <select
                                class="form-control input-sm" name="serviceability">
                                <option value="1"><fmt:message key="cars.service.good" /></option>
                                <option value="2"><fmt:message
                                        key="cars.service.repair" /></option>
                                <option value="3"><fmt:message key="cars.service.fault" /></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add"> <input
                            type="hidden" name="login" value="${user.login}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                            <fmt:message key="cars.addcar" />
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('auto', []);
        app.controller('carController', function($scope) {
            $scope.showForm = false;
            $scope.addCarFunc = function() {
                $scope.showForm = !$scope.showForm;
            }
        });
    </script>

    <br>
    <br>





    <div class="col-md-8 centerBlock">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="cars">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th><fmt:message key="profile.car.model" /></th>
                <th><fmt:message key="profile.car.type" /></th>
                <th><fmt:message key="profile.car.serviceability" /></th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${cars}" var="car">
                <tr>
                    <td>${car.idCar}</td>
                    <td><c:out value="${car.model}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${car.type}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${car.serviceability}" /></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"
                            id="car${car.idCar}" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo
                            modal</button></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>



    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <form method="POST" action="/Autostation/users">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <input id="val0" type="hidden" name="idCar" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"><fmt:message
                                    key="profile.car.model" /></label> <input
                                class="form-control input-sm" name="model" id="val1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"><fmt:message
                                    key="profile.car.type" /></label> <input class="form-control input-sm"
                                name="carsType" id="val2" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"><fmt:message
                                    key="profile.car.serviceability" /></label> <input
                                class="form-control input-sm" name="serviceability" id="val3" />
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("button.btn").click(function() {
            var id = this.id;
            $("table#cars tr").each(function(i) {
                if ($(this).find("#" + id).length > 0) {
                    var tr = $(this).children();
                    for (var i = 0; i < (tr.length); i++)
                        $("#val" + i).val(tr[i].innerHTML);
                }
            });
            $("div#myModal").show();
        });
    </script>
</body>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

> **UPDATED**

HTML CODE FROM BROWSER

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Профиль пользователя.</title>
<link href="/Autostation/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
 href="/Autostation/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Autostation/resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css">
<script src="/Autostation/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Autostation/resources/angular/angular.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  






<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
    aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
     class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
     class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>Автостанция</strong></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
   id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/Autostation/profile">Профиль</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Autostation/trips">Рейсы</a></li>
    
     





 <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Администрирование <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/Autostation/register">Добавить нового пользователя</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Autostation/userlist">Пользователи</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    
   </ul>
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   </form>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/Autostation/logout">Выйти</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="text-center">
 <h2>
  Автостанция
 </h2>
 <img height="100" width="300" alt="Logo" src='/Autostation/resources/logo/carLogo.png'>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8 centerBlock">
  <table class="table table-hover">
   <tr>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Фамилия</th>
    <th>Логин</th>
    <th>Email</th>

    <th>Количество автомобилей</th>

   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Serg</td>
    <td>Shapoval</td>
    <td>acid</td>
    <td>acidserg359@gmail.com</td>

    <td></td>

   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>


 <div class="centerBlock text-center col-xs-8 ">
  <div ng-app="auto" ng-controller="carController">

   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " ng-click="addCarFunc()">
    Добавить автомобиль
   </button>

   <div ng-show="showForm">
    <div class="col-xs-4 centerBlock text-center">
     <form action="/Autostation/users" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Модель </label> <input
        class="form-control input-sm" type="text"
        name="model" required="true" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Тип </label> <select
        class="form-control input-sm" name="type">
        <option value="1">Мини</option>
        <option value="2">Городская</option>
        <option value="3">Фургон</option>
        <option value="4">Грузовая</option>
       </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Техническое состояние </label> <select
        class="form-control input-sm" name="serviceability">
        <option value="1">Рабочая</option>
        <option value="2">В ремонте</option>
        <option value="3">Сломана</option>
       </select>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add"> <input
       type="hidden" name="login" value="acid">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
       Добавить автомобиль
      </button>
     </form>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>
  var app = angular.module('auto', []);
  app.controller('carController', function($scope) {
   $scope.showForm = false;
   $scope.addCarFunc = function() {
    $scope.showForm = !$scope.showForm;
   }
  });
 </script>

 <br>
 <br>





 <div class="col-md-8 centerBlock">
  <table class="table table-hover" id="cars">
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Модель</th>
    <th>Тип</th>
    <th>Техническое состояние</th>
    <th>Update</th>
   </tr>
   
  </table>
 </div>



 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
      aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="/Autostation/users">
     <div class="modal-body">

      <input id="val0" type="hidden" name="idCar" />
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Модель</label> <input
        class="form-control input-sm" name="model" id="val1" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Тип:</label> <label class="control-label" id="lb1">
       </label> <select
        class="form-control input-sm" name="type">
        <option value="1">Мини</option>
        <option value="2">Городская</option>
        <option value="3">Фургон</option>
        <option value="4">Грузовая</option>
       </select>
       <input type="hidden" id="val2">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Техническое состояние: </label> <label
        class="control-label" id="lb2"></label> <select
        class="form-control input-sm" name="serviceability">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Рабочая</option>
        <option value="2">В ремонте</option>
        <option value="3">Сломана</option>
       </select> <input type="hidden" id="val3" />
      </div>


     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>
  $("button.btn").click(function() {
   var id = this.id;
   $("table#cars tr").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).find("#" + id).length > 0) {
     var tr = $(this).children();
     for (var i = 0; i < (tr.length); i++) {
      $("#val" + i).val(tr[i].innerHTML);
     }
     $("label#lb1").text(tr[2].innerHTML);
     $("label#lb2").text(tr[3].innerHTML);
    }
   });
   $("div#myModal").show();
  });
 </script>
</body>
<script src="/Autostation/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you don't mix AngularJS and jQuery. But the bigger issue here is mixing AngularJS and JSP two completely different technologies to make page dynamic. However both AngularJS and jQuery run over the generated document in the browser so you might want to paste that generated HTML (click view source) in browser.

Comment: @bhantol what i need to do? what a problem? cause when i'm removing jquery script - all works fine

Comment: On the browser View Source and paste that html instead of pasting JSP. Or better if you create a plnkr out of the html.

Comment: I see 2 script tags before the html begins. And then the same scripts loaded again in the head section.

Comment: Why are you looking over all the table rows to find the one with the button with that id? Why don't you just navigate up to the table row from the clicked button? `var tr = $(this).closest("tr");`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the line

```
if ($(this).find("#" + id).length > 0) {
```

That error it is printing is that '#'. Not sure what you are trying to do.

But if you comment this block your error will be gone.

I mean the code fails at so many levels as JSP, AngularJS and jQuery is used all together. You might want to either remove AngularJS or reimplement that jQuery block of code in a Angular Way.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because your button doesn't have an ID. Therefore, if you try to do something like:

```
var id = this.id;
```

You'll get the error.

For that matter, simply assign an *id* value to your button, such as:

```
<button id="anything" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                            Добавить автомобиль
</button>
```